# Gemhoarder Steam Achievement, Not Finding Enough Gems?

Tags: pixeljunk-monsters

In order to achieve the accomplishment Gem Hoarder, one needs to complete this specified stage with 25 gems.  But I am unable to find this many!

Here I am with 22 gems at the final boss.  And the boss does not drop any.  So how do I got *all 25 gems necessary?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sell at the end a tower upgraded to black or two towers upgraded to purple. Besides money, towers at those levels give you gems too when sold.

Check this video: